# Save text and show him in another page

Tags: php, text, save

Hi i want to write text in one page and save him so it show in another page . Can you help me ?

i found something like this :

```
<?php
  $fileLocation = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/myfile.txt";
  $file = fopen($fileLocation,"w");
  $content = "Your text here";
  fwrite($file,$content);
  fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: What about store text in sessions?

Comment: I give an example: my javascript generate randomly quote and i want save that quote ,so that quote appear in certain page like myfavoritequotes.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save value on one page using your code written above in your question

**EDIT:**

```
 <?php
      if($_POST['submit'])
      {
      $fileLocation = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/myfile.txt";
      $file = fopen($fileLocation,"w");
      $content = $_POST['text'];
      fwrite($file,$content);
      fclose($file);
      header("Location: anotherpage.php");
      }
    ?>
   <form action="" method="POST">
   <textarea name="text"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
   </form>
```

then you can use [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) on next page to get the contents of that file again.

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents(getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/myfile.txt");
echo $homepage;
?>
```

**EDIT:**
OR

You can use session instead of saving text in a text file(if you want it to be stored for a temporary time period only)
then use given code

```
         <?php
          session_start();
          if($_POST['submit'])
          {
          $content = $_POST['text'];
          $_SESSION['text'] = $content;
          header("Location: anotherpage.php");
          }
        ?>
       <form action="" method="POST">
       <textarea name="text"></textarea>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
       </form>
```

On anotherpage.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$homepage= $_SESSION['text'];
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Comment: And some save button ? and textarea ? Can you help me with these because i dont absolutely know how to work with php

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this.. ?

```
<?php
  $fileLocation = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/myfile.txt";
  file_put_contents('somefile.txt',file_get_contents($fileLocation));
  header('location:anotherpage.php');
  exit;
?>
```

**`anotherpage.php`**

```
<?php
 echo file_get_contents('somefile.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<?php
      $fileLocation = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/myfile.txt";
      $file = fopen($fileLocation,"w");
      $content = "Your text here";
      fwrite($file,$content);
      fclose($file);
    ?>
```

Another Page

```
<?php
  $fileLocation = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/myfile.txt";
  $file = file_get_contents($fileLocation);
  echo $file;
?>
```